# Компилияция scss в css в Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

подскажите, как настроить компиляцию scss файлов в css

файл nuxt.config

```
css: [
    '@/assets/scss/app.scss',
    '@/assets/scss/media.scss',
    '@/assets/scss/mobile.scss',
  ],
  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  ** https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins
  */
  plugins: [
    {src: '~/plugins/vue-silentbox', mode: 'client' },
    {src: '~/plugins/vue-modal.js', mode: 'client' },
    {src: '~/plugins/vue-swiper.js', mode: 'client' },
  ],
  /*
  ** Auto import components
  ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-components
  */
  components: true,
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
  */
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxt/typescript-build'
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/style-resources',
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    "@nuxtjs/svg",
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    '@nuxtjs/device',
  ],
  styleResources: {
    sass: [
      '~/assets/scss/app.scss',
      '~/assets/scss/media.scss',
      '~/assets/scss/mobile.scss',
    ],
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

**1:** Устанавливаем зависимости:

```
npm install --save-dev node-sass sass-loader

или

yarn add --dev node-sass sass-loader
```

**2:** Добавляем плагин `@nuxtjs/style-resources` в ваш проект.

```
npm install --save-dev @nuxtjs/style-resources

или

yarn add --dev @nuxtjs/style-resources
```

**3:** Добавляем в ваш `assets` каталог новый каталог `sccs` (здесь будут храниться файлы с вашими глобальными переменными)

**4:** В файл конфигурации - `nuxt.config.js`, добавьте следующие параметры:

```
export default {
 ...
  css: ["~assets/scss/colors.scss"],
  modules: ["@nuxtjs/style-resources"],
  styleResources: {
    scss: ["./assets/scss/*.scss"]
  }
...
};
```

Пример - [@nuxtjs/style-resources](https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxtjsstyle-resources-zgfo5?file=/pages/index.vue)